# How to get data from a serialized array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Please help me print values to the console and the keys for the field "nickname." Here is the serialized data array in JSON:

```
[
    {"fields": {"user_permissions": [], "nickname": "\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d \u0422\u0443\u0440\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0432 \u0451\u043f\u0442\u0430", "groups": [], "avatar": "", "gender": 1, "skype": "dfsdf", "other": "zzzz", "phone": "2014-0921"}, "model": "app_accounts.userprofile_deferred_avatar_date_joined_email_fic679ed35161c7ba80f007b4235db5148", "pk": 4}, 
    {"fields": {"user_permissions": [], "nickname": "\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0427\u0435\u0445", "groups": [], "avatar": "", "gender": 2, "skype": "dfsdf", "other": "qqqqqq", "phone": "21"}, "model": "app_accounts.userprofile_deferred_avatar_date_joined_email_fic679ed35161c7ba80f007b4235db5148", "pk": 5}
]
```

I want the result to be something like this:

```
0: zzzzzz
1: qqqqqq
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your json has no field `"username"`

Comment: sorry. field names "nickname"

Comment: @dert: The first thing you need to do is parse your JSON in to JavaScript objects `var parsed = JSON.parse(json_data)`. Then take the result, and iterate it like a normal Array. `for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) console.log(parsed[i].fields.nickname);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print index and nickname, consider using forEach:

```
var users = [
    {"fields": {"user_permissions": [], "nickname": "\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d \u0422\u0443\u0440\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0432 \u0451\u043f\u0442\u0430", "groups": [], "avatar": "", "gender": 1, "skype": "dfsdf", "other": "zzzz", "phone": "2014-0921"}, "model": "app_accounts.userprofile_deferred_avatar_date_joined_email_fic679ed35161c7ba80f007b4235db5148", "pk": 4}, 
    {"fields": {"user_permissions": [], "nickname": "\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0427\u0435\u0445", "groups": [], "avatar": "", "gender": 2, "skype": "dfsdf", "other": "qqqqqq", "phone": "21"}, "model": "app_accounts.userprofile_deferred_avatar_date_joined_email_fic679ed35161c7ba80f007b4235db5148", "pk": 5}
] 

users.forEach(function(users, index) {console.log(index + ': ' + users.fields.nickname);});
```

will print:

```
0: Иван Тургенев ёпта
1: Антон Чех
```

Did you expect that ?

Answer (score 1):

The array you present in the question is [*not* serialized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Furthermore `username` Is no field in any object within the given array.

If you mean the field `other` within each `fields` object, you can retrieve that using `Array.map`:

```
var usernames = [
    {"fields": {"user_permissions": [], "nickname": "\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d \u0422\u0443\u0440\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0432 \u0451\u043f\u0442\u0430", "groups": [], "avatar": "", "gender": 1, "skype": "dfsdf", "other": "zzzz", "phone": "2014-0921"}, "model": "app_accounts.userprofile_deferred_avatar_date_joined_email_fic679ed35161c7ba80f007b4235db5148", "pk": 4}, 
    {"fields": {"user_permissions": [], "nickname": "\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0427\u0435\u0445", "groups": [], "avatar": "", "gender": 2, "skype": "dfsdf", "other": "qqqqqq", "phone": "21"}, "model": "app_accounts.userprofile_deferred_avatar_date_joined_email_fic679ed35161c7ba80f007b4235db5148", "pk": 5}
].map(function (v) { return v.fields.other });
//=> usernames now: ["zzzz", "qqqqqq"]
```

[**See also**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)...

Comment: I don't understand this. First, you're operating on JS objects, not serialized JSON data as described in the question. But you're also taking each object, serializing it and then parsing it before you extract its properties. This doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @squint: you're right, stringify/parse is nonsense here. Edited the answer. I was mislead by the term 'serialized' in the question header.